# Insert a Blank Page in Word After Every Page

Tags: vba, insert, selection, ms-word

I need to add blank pages after each page in Word documents and automate that either by a VBScript or by a macro.

I know the `Selection` object has a method to insert a page break, but how do I get the correct `Selection` objects?

Or is there a better, non-interactive method to get the job done?

Comment: Word doesn't really have a fixed page layout, because how a page is rendered depends on the current printer driver. What do you need this for anyway?

Answer (score 1):

You could use your macro recorder and during recording hit "Ctrl+g" for "Go To", select page and a number. This will give you a starting point how to get a page range.
Based on this, the following code will insert a blank page *before* each existing page but that should be good enough for a start, right?

```
Sub blanks()
Dim pag As Range, numPages As Long

numPages = ActiveDocument.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages)

For i = numPages To 1 Step -1
    Set pag = ActiveDocument.GoTo(wdGoToPage, wdGoToAbsolute, i)
    pag.InsertBreak WdBreakType.wdPageBreak
Next i
End Sub
```

As you can see, I am going backwards, starting at the last page. That is because if you started at the first page, how to know where your next page is after you insert blanks? ;-)